# using Laravel-Nwdart modules via addressbar

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

after installing `nWdart` laravel Module via composer, i create new module as `login` with this command:

```
php artisan module:make Login
```

serve command:

```
php artisan serve
```

after this command i'm trying to access to that via address bar or route like with this url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/login
```

unfortunately i can't find any document about this action and i get this error:

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this commands resolve my problem:

```
php artisan module:publish
php artisan module:dump
composer dump-autoload
```